# Liquibase using Java

Tags: java, liquibase

I have few questions regarding Liquibase:

1. How/Is it possible to create table programmatically without having a physical changelog file?
2. How/Is it possible to turn off creation of tables - databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock?
3. Does Liquibase support HBase or any other Big Data DBs? How?

Thanks

Comment: re 2) no (and it wouldn't make sense), re 3) no as well. The whole idea behind NoSQL databases is to **not** have a fixed schema that you need to manage.

Answer (score 2):

1: Check an example that I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796927/1572138).;

2: Check [this](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-nochangelogupdate/releases) liquibase extension.

3: You can check supported databases [here](http://www.liquibase.org/databases.html). 
If that's not available, you can check [how implement a new database class](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/Database).