# Liquibase XML generator

Tags: java, xml, database, generator, liquibase

Is there opensource/free liquibase (http://www.liquibase.org) xml generator?

Alternative to "Power Architect and Liquibase combo". Where can I create database model and then transform it to Liquibase XML format or transform pure sql to Liquibase XML?

Comment: Power Architect has free comunity version i missed that, looks pretty solid . But if there are other tools would still like to try .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't any available generator since I know.

Actually you can do it by your own by using [liquibase core classes](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/overview-summary.html).

An example of use:

```
// .. imports

// create a changelog
liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog databaseChangeLog = new liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog();

// create a changeset
liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet changeSet = new liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet("1", "prates", false, false, "", null, null, true, null, databaseChangeLog);

// create a drop table change
liquibase.change.core.DropTableChange dropTableChange = new liquibase.change.core.DropTableChange();

dropTableChange.setTableName("person");

changeSet.addChange(dropTableChange);

// add created changeset to changelog
databaseChangeLog.addChangeSet(changeSet);

// create a new serializer
XMLChangeLogSerializer xmlChangeLogSerializer = new XMLChangeLogSerializer();

String output = null;

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

xmlChangeLogSerializer.write(databaseChangeLog.getChangeSets(), baos);

output = baos.toString();

// print output
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: there is a Github project called liquify, https://github.com/daquino/liquify but I haven't tried it