# Is there a way to convert SQL queries to liquibase changelog format?

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I would like to know if it is possible to convert an existing SQL script into XML format of changelogs of a liquibase?

Comment: You can use the `<sql>` tag and run your "SQL script" that way inside your liquid base changelog. Otherwise I don't know about any tools to convert plain SQL into changelog XML file. I also suggest you to taka a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063169/liquibase-xml-generator

Answer (score 5):

You could use a detour via a database. Apply your script to a database of choice (that is supported by liquibase). Then use [`generateChangeLog`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) to generate the changelogs in xml from the database.