# Can you generate a Liquibase changelog XML file from SQL code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase, changelog

I have some SQL scripts that I'd like to convert into Liquibase XML changelogs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "convert into changelogs"?

If you don't need cross-database compatibility, you could just use the `sql` executor:

```xml
<changeSet id="testing123" author="me">
  <sql splitStatements="false">
    <!-- all your existing SQL paste here -->
  </sql>
</changeSet>
```

The `splitStatements=false` setting will make sure the complete SQL will be sent in one command; otherwise, Liquibase would split it into multiple commands at semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a detour via a database. Apply your script to a database of choice (that is supported by liquibase). Then use [generateChangeLog](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/snapshot/generate-changelog.html) to generate the changelogs in xml from the database. You will have the XML changelog generated for all the SQL scripts you have applied to your database.

Alternatively, have a look at answer on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063169/liquibase-xml-generator).